# Google Places Autocomplete JQuery plug-in not showing map

Tags: autocomplete, squarespace

I am not able to get the map to display on my Squarespace site. The autocomplete is working but the map is not showing up.

Here's my code:

```
 <form>
      <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Address" size="90" />
      <input id="find" type="button" value="Next" />
    </form>

<div class="map_canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>

    <pre id="logger">Log:</pre>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/logger.js"></script>
        <script>
      $(function(){

        var options = {
          map: ".map_canvas"
        };

        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete(options)
          .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
            $.log("Result: " + result.formatted_address);
          })
          .bind("geocode:error", function(event, status){
            $.log("ERROR: " + status);
          })
          .bind("geocode:multiple", function(event, results){
            $.log("Multiple: " + results.length + " results found");
          });

        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });

        $("#examples a").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").val($(this).text()).trigger("geocode");
          return false;
        });

      });
    </script>
```

And here are the scripts loading in the header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=true&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```